# implicit recomendation with ML spark and data frames

Tags: pyspark, recommendation-engine, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to use the new ML libraries with Spark and Dataframes for building a recommender with implicit ratings. 
My code

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import Row 

from pyspark.ml.recommendation import ALS

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

# create the dataframe (user x item)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)],
    ["user", "item"])
als = ALS() \
    .setRank(10) \
    .setImplicitPrefs(True)
model = als.fit(df)
print "Rank %i " % model.rank

model.userFactors.orderBy("id").collect()
test = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 0)], ["user", "item"])
predictions = sorted(model.transform(test).collect(), key=lambda r: r[0])
for p in predictions: print p
```

However, I run in this error

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'rating' given input columns user, item;

So, Not sure how to define the data frame

Comment: do you have any clue about what does the line of code represent `df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)],["user", "item"])`?

Answer (score 2):

I am confused because the MLLIB API has a separate API call for implicit

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html

```
val alpha = 0.01
val lambda = 0.01
val model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, rank, numIterations, lambda, alpha)
```

Comment: MLLIB is planned to be [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231840/difference-between-org-apache-spark-ml-classification-and-org-apache-spark-mllib). The ML package by abstracting  typical machine learning workflow tasks lets you leverage existing code for common tasks .e.g parameter tuning.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are trying to use (user, product) tuples, but you need (user, product, rating) triplets. Even for implicit ratings, you do need the ratings. You can use a constant like 1.0 if they are all the same.