# pySpark: Save ML Model

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

Can someone please give an example of how you would save a ML model in pySpark?

For

```
ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel
```

I try to use the following:

```
model.save("path")
```

but it does not seem to work.

Comment: What is the error you encounter? Some more detail (your stack trace and code) might help

Comment: It just says that it could not find any method with the same name (I am using Spark 1.6.1 by the way)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save ML model for future usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027767/save-ml-model-for-future-usage)

Comment: I'm running v2.2.0 and also get AttributeError: 'RandomForestRegressor' object has no attribute 'save'. google is failing me. all the docs seem to indicate this should work.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, your method signature is incorrect.

According to the docs you also need to pass in your spark context.

Docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=save#pyspark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel.save

Comment: But this belongs to mllib. Does the ml inherit those functions? In any case, it sounds reasonable since I did not make use of the spark context (sc). Thanks!

Comment: This is  better answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231840/difference-between-org-apache-spark-ml-classification-and-org-apache-spark-mllib however your methods should be the same. If this works, please accept this answer as the correct one!

Comment: I will try it out tomorrow because I do not have access to pyspark right now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In Spark 2.3.0, if you are using ML:

```
model.save("path")
```

Refer: [Spark ML model .save](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.save)

(*I just ran `LogisticRegression` and saved it.*)

---

But if you are using mllib, then as the other answer suggests use:

```
save(sc, path)
```

Refer: [Spark MLLib model .save](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=save#pyspark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel.save)