# spark - ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassifier vs pyspark.mllib.tree.DecisionTree

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

What's the difference between the ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassifier in ml and the mllib.tree.DecisionTree trainClassifier in mllib?

Answer (score 0):

The spark.mllib DecisionTree classifier is built on top of RDDs while the spark.ml provides a further API built on top of DataFrames for constructing ML pipelines.  It's recommended to use spark.ml due to the advantages of DataFrames optmizations.

Here's a good post I found after searching more of the forums:
[Difference between org.apache.spark.ml.classification and org.apache.spark.mllib.classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231840/difference-between-org-apache-spark-ml-classification-and-org-apache-spark-mllib)